# Errors importing UTF8 file to mathematica

Tags: import, character-encoding

I'm trying to import this file:

```
Import["https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35192406/jarlaxxe_tweets.\
csv", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"]
```

But I am getting errors like:

```
$CharacterEncoding::utf8: The byte sequence {240} could not be interpreted as a character in the UTF-8 character encoding. >>
```

Any idea why? And any solution?

Comment: It's not happy with one of your Emoji characters... This one  seems to be the problem.

Comment: ... in fact there are others which are also not being translated, such as  <- (that wasn't me adding a smiley face, just showing you what they are :)

Comment: _New in Mathematica 10: Emoji support!_

Comment: Anyone knows any fix or workaround?

Comment: easy to repair after importing - just replace the four characters with something else... eg `StringReplace[#, "ð" ~~ ___ -> ":)"] & /@ text`. Workround: don't use Emoji? Pre-process text before importing?

Comment: The solution offered by cormullion doesn't work for me. The pattern replaces too much of the text. Have you tested it?